# Outlook - what is this toolbar that appears when I'm typing a message?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

I'm a heavy user of the keyboard and I've noticed this toolbar appearing from time-to-time when I'm typing a message in Outlook

[image: Image of inline toolbar in message]

- What is it?
- What key combo have I pressed to get it to appear?
- Is it useful?
- Can I turn it off?

If I press Esc, Outlook unhelpfully offers to discard the entire message for me which is not my intent here. I need to remove my fingers and mouse this one closed which I don't like or want.

Comment: I don't have this version of Outlook, but it looks like the [Read Aloud function](https://oneminuteofficemagic.com/2019/01/14/using-the-read-aloud-feature-in-outlook/)

Comment: @davidmneedham it does indeed. Do you want to write that up as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the Read Aloud function. You can disable this in the Outlook options under **File** | **Options** | **Ease of Access**. Uncheck **Show Read Aloud** to disable to the feature.

[image: Outlook Read Aloud Settings]

*Source: [Using the Read Aloud Feature in Outlook](https://oneminuteofficemagic.com/2019/01/14/using-the-read-aloud-feature-in-outlook/)*